# Firebase Reward Referrals using Firestore

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to deploy a simple Firebase Cloud function.

I want to use Firestore to reward a referrer with in-app credits when someone that they referred signs up.

This is my `node.js` function.

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate(event => {

        let documentRef = admin.firestore.doc(`users/${event.data.referredBy}/cats/accountInformation`);

        console.log("Error giving hints:", documentRef);

        return documentRef.data.ref.set({

            credits: credits + 5

                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("Error giving hints:", error);
                }),
        }, {
            merge: true
        });

    });
```

I am quite unfamiliar with `node.js`. I have looked around and tried different things as far as syntax, and none of them have worked. Any help would be appreciated. I can't find much documentation on this.

Comment: I hate coming on to this site. If one person posts a question, chances are other people are facing the same problem as well. Point the OP in the right direction instead of this stupid unprogressive behaviour of down voting posts with no reason.

Comment: If you want some constructive feedback, my recommendation would be to explain a bit more about what you have already tried.

Comment: Is that code working? Im pretty sure `credits: credits + 5` wont work because you need to query the original credits for current user first, then operate the number and then write back.

Comment: I was just trying different syntax, and I didn't save the code. I am not really familiar with node.js so I cannot recreate what I wrote. I don't see how what I've tried in the past is relevant to the problem I am having. Which is that the function above isn't right syntactically.

Comment: @KarloA.López its not working. I thought that might be part of the problem but I don't know how to get the value in the credits field and apply it to a variable. I have a feeling that it shouldn't be in the return function but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of how to drag the written information without making another request, just with the onCreate firestore event:

```
    exports.createUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate(event => {

//Doc ref 
let documentRef = admin.firestore.doc(`users/${event.data.referredBy}/cats/accountInformation`);

//Get the value you want from that document 
documentRef.get().then((doc) => {
  var docData = doc.data();

  var currentCredits = docData.credits;
  var newCredits = currentCredits + 5;

  //Then you return the promise, this time pointing the new ref
  return documentRef.set({credits:newCredits});
});


});
```

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that the `credits` value isn't going to be coming from the Firestore document returned by the `event` data, but from a different  document which the `documentRef` variable references. This is because I want to reward the referrer and not the user that just signed up. How would I reference that document? This seems to be the main issue that I haven't figured out. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Im sorry, didn't read the details of the question, check my updated answer.

Comment: Ah! Okay. I couldn't really understand the `get` function. I'll try and deploy your answer and check back in a few minutes after I've tested it out

Comment: It still isn't working. For some reason every log on my console is blank. For some reason the function isn't getting triggered. I will try to contact Firebase support. If you know what the issue is then please, let me know. Otherwise, until then.

Comment: Are you deploying the function? or just serving it?

Comment: I am deploying the function